# Regex Expression Escape Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some difficulty getting an expression to work. I've got it working if the line terminators and slashes are not excaped.

`The Server Job .([^\\]*).([^\\]*).([^\\]*) has Completed Abnormally on the Server Master (.*)\.\n\nJOB ID: (\d+)\n\nFollow Batch abend and escalation procedures.`
https://regex101.com/r/5TrEBB/1

Example Text:

```
The Server Job \FACET\Batch\SERV1254 SERVER IGX OUTPUT FILES CREATION has Completed Abnormally on the Server Master SER130P.

JOB ID: 10560914

Follow Batch abend and escalation procedures.
```

However, I need it to work with both example texts like so:

`The Server Job \\FACET\\Batch\\SERV1254 SERVER IGX OUTPUT FILES CREATION has Completed Abnormally on the Server Master SER130P.\n\nJOB ID: 10560914\n\nFollow Batch abend and escalation procedures.`

Note the escape \ and \n. It is basically and if one or two slashes and if line break or \n\n.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use ``\\n`` instead of ``\n`` in the regex you have?

Comment: The text can come in formated or raw with the formatting escaped. I need to account for both, if possible. I updated the question, for some reason the escaped chars were not included.

Comment: Use '\\?\\' That makes the first slash optional.

Comment: You can also use: '(\n|\\n)' to support both escaped and non escaped line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works with both:

```
The Server Job (?:\\|\\\\)([^\\]*)(?:\\|\\\\)([^\\]*)(?:\\|\\\\)([^\\]*) has Completed Abnormally on the Server Master (.*)\.(?:\n\n|\\n\\n)JOB ID: (\d+)(?:\n\n|\\n\\n)Follow Batch abend and escalation procedures.
```

Whenever you have a possible escaped/non-escaped character, use an or group and avoid its capture.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot, I guess I can stop banging my head on the desk. Update regex101 url https://regex101.com/r/5TrEBB/2

Comment: funny funny funny

Comment: One more addition, is there a way to build it to account for possibly more group like so: `The Server Job \Books of Record (BOR)\PBOR\PBOR_DAILY\INF02252A Business Org Inbound Process GRP\010 UNX02252A0 Business Org Inbound Process has Completed Abnormally on the Server Master WTES130P.`

Comment: This [works](https://regex101.com/r/5TrEBB/3) for 3 to 5 groups: `The Server Job (?:(?:\\|\\\\)([^\\]*)){3,5} has Completed Abnormally on the Server Master (.*)\.(?:\n\n|\\n\\n)JOB ID: (\d+)(?:\n\n|\\n\\n)Follow Batch abend and escalation procedures.`

Comment: Would it be possible to update the regex101 https://regex101.com/r/r5w0pJ/3 I updated it without the non-capturing groups to simplify the expression